# Second Activity call Main Activity Function crashed in Android

Tags: java, android

this is the code in Second Activity `OnCreate`

```
final Button arrayBtn = (Button) findViewById(buttonQtyID[i]);
            arrayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ClearQtyBtnColor(); 
                    arrayBtn.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xffff9999, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    MainActivity  cls2= new MainActivity();

                    String Price = cls2.CheckUnitPrice("NORMAL"); // ERROR AT HERE
                    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Harga_lblPrice);
                    //view.setText((Double.parseDouble(Price) * Integer.parseInt(arrayBtn.getText().toString()))+"");
                }
             });
```

this is the coding in Main Activity

```
public Cursor DB_GetUnitPrice(){
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    try { 
    myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
    } catch (IOException ioe) { 
    throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
    }  
    try {  
    myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
    }catch(SQLException sqle){  
    throw sqle;  
    }
    SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String Insert_Data="Select Normal_Rate,Discounted_Rate FROM Tbl_Rate WHERE Route_ID="+global.Route_ID+" AND ((From_LocationID="+global.From_LocationID+" AND To_LocationID="+global.To_LocationID+") OR (From_LocationID="+global.To_LocationID+" AND To_LocationID="+global.From_LocationID + "))";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(Insert_Data, null);

    //c.close(); // cannot will error
    //db.close(); // cannot will error
    //myDbHelper.close();
    return c;
}

public String CheckUnitPrice(String PriceType){
    if ((global.To_LocationID != 0) && (global.From_LocationID != 0)) {
            Cursor c = DB_GetUnitPrice();
            double Normal_Rate = 0;
            double Discounted_Rate = 0;
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                Normal_Rate = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Normal_Rate"));
                Discounted_Rate = c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("Discounted_Rate"));
            }
            if (PriceType.equalsIgnoreCase("NORMAL")){
                return String.format("%.2f",(Normal_Rate));
            }else{
                return String.format("%.2f",(Discounted_Rate));
            }
    }else{
        return "0.00";
    }
}
```

this is my global variable declaration in Class Global

```
public class Global extends Application {
    String Driver_Code;
    String Driver_Name;
    long Driver_ID;

    long Vehicle_ID;
    String Plat_No;

    long Route_ID;

    int From_LocationID;
    int To_LocationID;
    String From_LocationName;
    String To_LocationName;
    int From_Tag;
    int To_Tag;

}
```

this is the Log cat Error log

```
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at com.example.abc2.MainActivity.CheckUnitPrice(MainActivity.java:246)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at com.example.abc2.SecondActivity$2.onClick(SecondActivity.java:58)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-02 14:13:48.718: E/AndroidRuntime(10643):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

calling `CheckUnitPrice` on Main activity are working fine, can return the Price from Sqlite, but when calling from another activity, occurs problem. please help

Comment: What is "global" and where have you declared it??

Comment: @SiddharthVyas is a global variable i store the value inside

Comment: Where have you declared it?

Comment: Use "Global" instead of "global".

Comment: @SiddharthVyas nothing different

Answer (score 0):

You should make the variables in Global class as public, and get the access to the class from the ApplicationContext.

```
Global state = ((Global) getApplicationContext());
int value = state.To_LocationID
```

Also, make an entry in Manifest file under the `application` tag which will let the system know about your application class.

```
android:name="Global"
```

Note: You should make member variable in `Global` as private and generate `getters and setters` for these variables. Avoid direct access to variables.

Comment: what is `getters and setters ` ?

Comment: all ur answer are in my code, global=((Global)getApplicationContext()); i had declare in my code too, application tag are named to abc.example.abc2.Global.  it is still can't work

Comment: getter and setter are the public methods for the variable which are responsible for fetching and setting the value of variable.            // Getter `public int getToLocationID(){ return To_LocationID;}` `public void setToLocationID(int value){ To_LocationID = value; }`. You can also auto-generate them in eclipse. Go to your class i.e Global, Right Click--> Select Source--> Select Generate Getters and Setters. Now select the variable whose getters and setters you want.

Answer (score 0):

If MainActivity class extends Activity you cannot use this construction:

```
MainActivity  cls2= new MainActivity();
```

Create simple class and make static methods inside it.

Comment: Yes, MainActivity are extends activity, and  `CheckUnitPrice` are inside MainACtivity , any idea to call  `CheckUnitPrice` this function?

Comment: place your method inside other class. For example you can use Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. you need to give variable as `public static` then only you can get that variable

```
public class Global extends Application {
    public static String Driver_Code;
    public static String Driver_Name;
    public static long Driver_ID;

    public static long Vehicle_ID;
    public static String Plat_No;

    public static long Route_ID;

    public static int From_LocationID;
    public static int To_LocationID;
    public static String From_LocationName;
    public static String To_LocationName;
    public static int From_Tag;
    public static int To_Tag;

}
```

You can access variable like below..

```
if ((Global.To_LocationID != 0) && (Global.From_LocationID != 0)) {
```